# Dynamic PHP Content via Query Strings

Tags: php, arrays, string, dynamic

I'm wanting to use a pair of query strings to generate specific page content

query string example:
example.co.uk/index.php?brand=apple&video=red

I've managed to use some simple PHP to replace the div id's with query brand with some help as follows:

```
<?php 
$recognised_brands = array( 
  "apple", 
  "orange", 
  // etc 
); 

$default_brand = $recognised_brands[0]; // use first from list arbitrarily. 

$brand_to_use = isset($_GET['brand']) && in_array($_GET['brand'], $recognised_brands) 
  ? $_GET['brand'] 
  : $default_brand; 

echo '<div id="' . $brand_to_use . '"></div>';  
?>
```

However I'm unsure on how to do similar for the second query called video.

If for example they query is ?brand=apple&video=red

Then I'd want to replace the video var in the page code to the correct number for red but I don't know how to add a list of these variables based on the video query like: red => 1 which then echo's 1 into the correct area?

Also based on the video selected I'd like part of the heading text to change and a paragraph of code below it but also unsure on where is best to specify this:

To try and clarify:

I have my brand query sorted
I need to make my video query populate multiple areas headings, video id and content div's but not sure how!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, this would do what you are looking for:

```
$videoToNum = array("red" => 1, 
                    "blue" => 2, 
                    "yellow" => 3);

$videoValue = ((isset($_GET['video']) && isset($videoToNum[$_GET['video']])) ? $videoToNum[$_GET['video']] : null);

if($videoValue) {
    echo '<div id="' . $videoValue . '"></div>';  
}
```

The question is rather vague though, so you may want to elaborate further if this doesn't help.

**Edit:** Here's an example of a switch as discussed in the comments:

```
$video = (isset($_GET['video']) ? $_GET['video'] : null);

if($video) {
    switch($video) {
        case "red":
            //do red stuff
            break;
        case "blue":
            //do blue stuff
            break;
        case "yellow":
            //do yellow stuff
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi David thank you - sorry I'm struggling with how to write this:

OK so I have branding working and now with your code I can use this to select the correct video var number so if the query says red it can replace the var number 1 for eg.

however also for the query red I need to replace part of a heading text area and insert a div with content further down the page - but don't know how to reference that on the page

Comment: Thanks Mahn - I'm not sure - I just need red to do multiple things in multiple places:

ie IF red:

replace heading area
insert div content
replace video var

and then the same needs to be for blue and yellow?

Comment: So a switch should do... you put everything you need to change depending on the video variable inside the each block of the switch. (again, see the edit of the question)

Comment: Thanks Mahn, I've not used a switch before - do you think you could show me an example as how I'd then link to a specific part of the switch in the page ie the heading area say it was to go inside a pair of divs what would the php command be to reference this 1 area from the switch?

Comment: You could save the div text in a variable, say $headingArea, when you process the switch; you can then echo it wherever it's supposed to go.

Comment: something like this:

case "red":
            $headingArea "example text"
            break;


then reference it in the code like:

<?php echo '$headingArea>';  ?>

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant. Of course, the switch will have to be processed before echoing $headingArea; ie put it before the header.

Comment: Thanks Mahn, I left it over whilst checking - I've implimented the code but I've not done it right I don't think as the page won't load - am I using the correct bracketing for the various lines

$Heading 'EXAMPLE HEADING'
or should it be " " or something else?

Comment: You have to assign variables like you would do outside of the switch block, like $heading = "something" and so on.